# python uuid weird bug

Tags: python, uuid

I first tried with the interpreter to produce uuid's with python's uuid module. I did the following:

```
>>>import uuid
>>>uuid.uuid1()
UUID('d8904cf8-48ea-11e0-ac43-109add570b60')
```

So far so good. I create a simple little function to produce the uuid's.

```
import uuid

def get_guid():
    return uuid.uuid1()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print get_guid()
```

and I get the following error:

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'uuid1'

Ok...hmm...go back to the interpreter and now it too is broken. I get the same error running the same code I used to test this. I am baffled. What makes uuid break like this? And what is wrong with my code?

I am using python 2.6

Comment: i bet you named your script uuid.py, don't do it change the name of your script.

Comment: Is the name of your file uuid.py?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Your test file name is most likely named `uuid.py`

When you went back to the interpreter, you launched the interpreter from the same directory, which by default, will first look for the module name to import in your current working directory.

Just change your test file name to something else, i.e. `uuid_test_snippet.py`

Comment: that was the trick...stupid mistake...lesson learned...thanks!

Comment: If you're running python 2.6+, you can also do `from __future__ import absolute_import` as well.

Comment: Lol. What a failure. Thanks!